# Consulta en PostgreSQL devuelve NoneType

Tags: python, postgresql

Después de crear un usuario en mi base de datos en mi aplicación implementada en Heroku, entro en la página de registro si tiene éxito. Cuando intento iniciar sesión, hace la siguiente consulta:

```
result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", [username])
```

Sin embargo, me da el siguiente error:

> 018-07-03T15:02:47.167067+00:00 app[web.1]: File "app.py", line 140,
>   in login 2018-07-03T15:02:47.167069+00:00 app[web.1]: if result > 0:
>   2018-07-03T15:02:47.167071+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: '>' not
>   supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Sin embargo, la consulta de registro fue exitosa y estoy bastante seguro de que proporcioné las credenciales correctas. Aquí está el código involucrado:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get Form Fields
        username = request.form['username']
        password_candidate = request.form['password']

        # Create cursor
        #cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur = conn.cursor()

        # Get user by username
        result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", [username])

        if result > 0:
            # Get stored hash
            data = cur.fetchone()
            password = data['password']
```

Comment: No sé si usas Python como lenguaje, lo cierto es que no conozco esa sintaxis. A pesar de eso el error es muy descriptivo: `'>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'` el problema es que al parecer en `result` tú estás metiendo todo el resultado del `SELECT` puesto que usas un  `SELECT * ...`  y luego intentas comparar si *eso*  es mayor que `0`. Quizá deberías usar un `SELECT COUNT(*)` o extraer de `result` un valor numérico para poder compararlo con `0`. No te puedo decir como hacerlo porque no sé usar el lenguaje en el que estás trabajando. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si, utiliso Python. Extrañamente funcionó bien con MySQL. Este viene del [repositorio de B. Traversy](https://github.com/bradtraversy/myflaskapp/blob/master/app.py) para una aplicación simple con usuarios y artículos con Flask y una base de datos MySQL

Answer (score 0):

El método `execute` por sí mismo no retorna nada, la información la obtienes usando algunos de los métodos [`fetch*`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#fetch). Si estás buscando un registro único entonces lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar `fetchone` y validar el resultado:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = %s", [username])
data = cur.fetchone()

if data:
   password = data['password']
   # ...
```

El método `fetchone` retornará `None` si no hay ningún dato disponible.

Comment: Muchas gracisa por su respuesta. Sin embargo obtengo con ella este nueva error : `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str` con `password = data['password']` que esta extrano. Voy a intentar con `data[4]` pero es una pena porque trajo visibilidad

Comment: @Marine1 asumí por el contenido de tu pregunta que habías configurado el cursor para usar nombres de los campos en vez de índices. Pues sí, en ese caso tendrías que usar los índices: 0, 1, etc. para obtener los campos.